# SVM Scikit-learn - Data Augmentation possible?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network, svm, data-augmentation

are there any functions in Scikit-learn or another library which support Data Augmentation for SVMs?
Anything like the ImageDataGenerator in Keras, just for SVMs?

It is really an important question for me which I have been trying to answer for a long time, so I would be very grateful for any tip.

Comment: What about this data augmentation process would be specific to SVM's?

Comment: @MaximeKan so far my search for such a library has been unsuccessful.

Comment: @MaximeKan Do you have a hint?

Comment: What type of data are you using?